# Want to display different text every few seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have such a problem:

I have an array of data, and I have an array of time.
These are the arrays:

```
  const Reps = {
    TimeOfMove: [1, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4.5, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15.5],
    ScoreOfMove: [60, 85, 42, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 90, 40, 0, 20],
  };
```

After a second I want to display the number 60, after 2.5 seconds the number 85, and so these ...

This is the code I've been trying to do so far, but it's not working for me

```
import React from "react";

function App() {

  const Reps = {
    TimeOfMove: [1, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4.5, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15.5],
    ScoreOfMove: [60, 85, 42, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 90, 40, 0, 20],
  };
  const scoreValue = (time, score) => {
    time.forEach((timePoint, i) => {
      setInterval(() => {
        <p>{score[i]}</p>
      }, timePoint * 1000);
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {scoreValue(Reps.TimeOfMove, Reps.ScoreOfMove)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to display different text each time, according to the time it appears.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a state (*currentScore*) and set the value to it on interval, This is done by the forEach loop and setInterval.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [currentScore, setCurrentStore] = useState(null);
  const Reps = {
    TimeOfMove: [1, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4.5, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15.5],
    ScoreOfMove: [60, 85, 42, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 90, 40, 0, 20],
  };

  useEffect(() => {
      Reps.TimeOfMove.forEach((time, index) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
              setCurrentStore(Reps.ScoreOfMove[index])
          }, time * 1000)
      })
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <p>{currentScore}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Better to trigger 
`Reps.TimeOfMove.forEach((time, index) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          setCurrentStore(Reps.ScoreOfMove[index])
      }, time * 1000)
  })` Inside a `useEffect` this way the re-render, when the state updates, will not cause the forEach to be executed again, I believe.

Comment: Something like this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-hooks-oebco?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I think yes we need to wrap it inside useeffect.

Answer (score -2):

This should work.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    const [score, setScore] = useState('');

    const Reps = {
        TimeOfMove: [1, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4.5, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15.5],
        ScoreOfMove: [60, 85, 42, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 90, 40, 0, 20],
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        Reps.TimeOfMove.forEach((time, index) => {
            const interval = setInterval(() => setScore(Reps.ScoreOfMove[index]), time * 1000);
            return () => {
                clearInterval(interval);
            };
        })

    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {score}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -3):

here a solution in Vanilla JS, you can apply in React or where you want

This is a recursive solution.

```
const arrs = {
  TimeOfMove: [1, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4.5, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15.5],
  ScoreOfMove: [60, 85, 42, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 90, 40, 0, 20],  
}

const runTimer = (index) => {
  if (index === arrs.TimeOfMove.length - 1) {
    console.log('Timer is finished!')
    return;
  }
 
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(arrs.ScoreOfMove[index]);
    runTimer(index + 1);
  }, arrs.TimeOfMove[index] * 1000)
}

const INDEX_START = 0;

runTimer(INDEX_START);
```

Aditional, share codepen
https://codepen.io/niko20/pen/MWpryRB

if you want show text "score of move" in DOM can use useState of ReactJS and set score when timer run.